# Questions about functions that return pointers

Tags: c, cs50

I'm trying to understand some of the distribution code

```
typedef struct person
{
    struct person *parents[2];
    char alleles[2];
}
person;

person *create_family(int generations);

int main(void)
{
    person *p = create_family(GENERATIONS);
}
```

Why do we have to put the star operator inside of our prototype. Is it always necessary to include the star operator inside of prototypes?

Comment: The star means pointer.

Comment: It's not an operator, it's part of the type declaration. `person*` is a pointer to a `person`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Barmar has already pointed this out in the comments: the `*` is not a operator applied to a function prototype, it is instead referring to a pointer return type.

The `create_family(int generations)` function is returning a `person*` or in other words a pointer, `*`, to a `struct person`.

You could also write it like this:

```
person* create_family(int generations);
```

Or like this:

```
person * create_family(int generations);
```

This is similar to declaring a pointer variable to a `person` struct, the `*` is part of the type declaration of the variable.

```
person *johnDoe = NULL;
```

On the other hand, the `*` symbol in, a different context, is also used as the dereference operator. This is the same symbol, but completely different meaning, operator instead of part of a type declaration.

```
(*johnDoe).alleles[0] = 'G';
(*johnDoe).alleles[1] = 'T';
```